# Implementing Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager tracking codes on a Wordpress site with Personal plan

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, web-traffic, wordpress.com

I have a Wordpress website and have the Personal plan.

My goal is to implement the tracking code of the Google Tag Manager on each site.

When I am on the Wordpress site in the HTML view, I should be able to paste one tracking code as close to the opening `<head>` tag as possible on every page of my website but this is not possible.

That´s why I had a talk with somebody from the Wordpress Support team and their answer was the following:

> I believe the code for Google Analytics is meant to go in the header of the site. Since WordPress.com is a fully managed environment, we don't have access to the header code.
>   Instead, we have a built in Google Analytics option available as part of the Business upgrade.

The issue is I don´t want to spend 25$ a month just to have Google Analytics integrated on my website. There must be also a way for somebody like me with a Personal plan to implement the tracking codes.
When I tried to implement them, they were not hidden on the website which should not be the case (because "hidden" is in the code).

Did anybody of you have the same issue like I am facing?

P.S.: There are also Plugins for Google Analytics but with my plan I can´t upload any Plugins. :/

Comment: I wanted to upload a picture but it is unfortunately not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I integrated the code on a text widget. It worked just fine. If you dont give title to the widget, its even completly invisible. so dont spend unecessary money